# disable links except one link regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have to disable all links that users had written in comments except one specified link (let's say for this example it would be **specified-link.com**).

When I was writing my regex for this case I was looking at the situations where user has written string which contains string of most popular tld: **.com, .net, .org...** and strings **http** and **https**

My regex for this situation looks like this:

```
@([^\s]*((\\.com)|(http)|(https))[^\s]*)@
```

I have forgotten about these two situations:
1) uppercase combination like **.CoM** etc
2) I have to show links that contains links of **specified-link.com**.

Also, are there any other situations that I have to look for when hiding links?

I have tried and googled but I couldn't manage to refactor my regex to look for these two situations. How should it looks like to cover up this situations?

Comment: I have just found that I have to put (?i) inside regex to make it case insensitive. Where I have to put it to make whole regex case insensitive, not just part of it?

Comment: I think it's easier to iterate over all links (using a simple regex) and then disable each link unless it's allowed (using another simple regex).

Comment: Wheres the regex being used? `http|https` can just be `https?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?specified-link\.com[^\s]*@
```

Where `https://` and `www.` are optional